# anaconda will not let me import files and therefore I cannot delete it or redownload it

Tags: python, anaconda

I accidentally deleted a calendar.py file from anaconda, so every time I try to import something I get a "no module named calendar". To delete it, you have to install a deleter package, which I can't do. I can't redownload it if it's already on my system. How do I delete anaconda?

Comment: [Uninstalling Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) in the future ask Google first, StackOverflow is really for programming problems

Comment: thank you but as I said in the post the link info won't work as I am missing a module and cannot install anything including the cleaner.

Comment: _To delete it, you have to install a deleter package_ You can uninstall most of Anaconda without having to install anything, see [Uninstalling Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).